# equation of plane in cartesian and vector form

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry

We have equation of plane planes in both cartesian and vector form.Do they represent the same thing and if then why?Vectors and points are really different things so i get confused everytime they derive the plane equation using position vectors....is there a reason for using using position vectors and other vectors defined using it in the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the vector equation and the coordinate equation for a plane both represent the same thing. Often times, we use vectors to find the equation of a plane simply because doing it that way is the easiest. I'll explain the connection between the two.

Say that we fix a point $P_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on some plane, and we find a vector $\textbf{n} = \langle a,b,c\rangle$ that is normal to the plane as you can see [here at Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html). To find the equation of the plane, what we would like is to be able to describe any other point $P = (x,y,z)$ on the plane. We can do this in a very simple way using vector manipulations.

Say that $\textbf{r}$ is the position vector of point $P$ (the vector going from the origin to point $P$), and $\textbf{r}_0$ is the position vector of point $P_0$. Then, the vector $\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}_0$ goes from point $P_0$ to point $P$. Now, since planes are "flat" we know that if point $P$ is to be on the plane, the vector $\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}_0$ must be perpendicular to the vector $\textbf{n}$. This means that

$$
\textbf{n} \cdot (\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}_0
) = 0 \tag{1}
$$

This is the equation of the plane in vector form. Often, this is not the end result you are looking for. Because you want everything in terms of coordinates. But it is not too hard to get to the form we want. Taking the vector equation and plugging in the coordinates we have

$$
\begin{align}
0 &=\langle a,b,c \rangle \cdot \left[ \langle x,y,z \rangle - \langle x_0,y_0,z_0 \rangle \right] \\ &= \langle a,b,c \rangle \cdot \langle x - x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0 \rangle \\ & = a(x-x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0)
\end{align}
$$

And so at last, here is the coordinate equation:

$$
a(x-x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0) = 0 \tag{2}
$$

Sometimes this is multiplied out, and all of the non-$x,y,z$ terms are collected on the right hand side and given a name like $D$. That makes the equation look like this

$$
ax + by + cz = D \tag{3}
$$

where $D = ax_0 + by_0 + cz_0$. So, you now have a few equivalent forms to work with, and what you choose to use depends entirely on the information you are given. For instance, if you are asked to find the equation of the plane, passing through the point $P_0 = (1, 2, 3)$ normal to the vector $\textbf{n} = \langle 5, 4, 7 \rangle$ you can immediately use $(2)$ to write $5(x - 1) + 4(y - 2) + 7(z - 3) = 0$. On the other hand, if you are asked, for instance, to find a vector normal to the plane $3x + y + 2z = 24$ you can deduce from $(3)$ immediately that $\textbf{n} = \langle 3,1,2 \rangle$.

Comment: So in 3D we have to use position vectors and other vectors defined from it to derive the equation and then simplifying it further to get in cartesian coordinates....is this the only method for finding equations in 3D ?

Comment: Another option would be to observe that any cross section of a plane is always a line. Which would lead you to deduce that a plane is an equation of the form $z = ax + by + c$ (here the $a$, $b$, and $c$ are $\textit{not}$ the same as the ones in my answer above). Then you could derive the equation of a plane passing through three points $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$. This would involve plugging in the coordinates of these points into the general equation to get a system of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns, and solving this system for $a,b,$ and $c$. It would be a real pain.

Comment: So anyway, yes it is often times easier to use vectors when working in 3D.

Comment: So we can use vectors to solve any question in 3D

Comment: More specifically position vectors

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. Saying $\textit{any question}$ is a very broad statement so I hesitate to answer yes to that. But I would imagine that $\textit{most}$ questions you will see in a homework setting that involve equations of planes and lines and such in 3D can be solved using vector methods.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my question,"Can we apply the concept of vectors to any 3D question or there are some restrictions to it?

Comment: I see no reason why you cannot apply vectors to try to answer any question involving 3D space. Whether you can $\textit{always}$ find a satisfactory solution in this way is a question that I don't think has an answer.

Comment: Glad you explained that to me.I always have second doubts using vectors in 3D because it somehow doesn't fit with me and my teacher didn't explain this to me in detail so your answer really helps me with this concept.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"Vectors and points are really different things" they aren't though. If you ever study vector spaces you'll discover that points are actually vectors. I know this can be confusing. So when you see a point used as a vector imagine that it's not the point that we are using it's rather te positional vector of said point . If the point is $P$ the positional vector would be $\vec{OP}$ where $O$ is the origin